# how do I save a random choice when I myself don't know what the choice will be?

Tags: python, random, while-loop

```
import random

print(
    "Do you think you know all the animals?! if yes then this game is for \033[1myou!\033[0m")
print("\033[7m""Let the game begin! ""\033[0m")
animals = ("ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar").split()
you_chose = []
animal = random.choice(animals)
hint = random.choice(list(animal))
used_hints = []
lives = 6
hint_count = 6
while True:
    print()
    letter = input("please type a letter to begin:  ").lower()
    if letter in you_chose:
        print("\033[31m Error doublicate letter\033[0m")
        continue
    else:
        you_chose.append(letter)
    if letter in animal:
        print("Congrats, you found a letter! keep going.")
    else:
        print("Not in there keep trying")
        lives = -1
        want_hint = input("Would you like a hint?(yes \ No)\n: ").lower()
        if want_hint == "yes":
            for want_hint in hint:
                if want_hint not in used_hints and want_hint not in you_chose:
                    hint_count += 1
                    print(hint, end="")
                    used_hints.append(want_hint)
                else:
                    continue
    for letter in animal:
        if letter in you_chose:
            print(letter, end="")
        else:
            print("*", end="")
```

#question- i need to save the randomised animal which then be turned to a list to be used as hints for the game but as the games in a while true loop the first time we ask for a hint itll give the original animal but next time the hint becomes from cat to dog i need to save the value the random choice gave before turning it into a hint i tried the seed funtion as im new to code thought itll work well didnt

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, this will make the animals string input into a list:

animals = list(animals)
animal = random.choice(animals)
print(animal)

or try:
animals = ['cat','human','dog','bird'...]
animal = random.choice(animals)
print(animal)

Comment: I can't print the animal itll ruin the game if the animal is printed I'm trying to create a hangman with hints